# Accessing canvas in Flowplayer

Tags: events, plugins, configuration, canvas, flowplayer

we are using the Flowplayer ([Documentation](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/)) in one of our webprojects.

I want to change (or hide) the canvas **after** the video has started. I can hook it to the clip-event  `"onStart"`, but I can't access the canvas object/plugin.

I already tried:

- $f('playerid').getPlugin('canvas').hide()
- $f('playerid').getCanvas().hide()

My player settings are:

```
var player_settings = {
    key: '...',
    logo: {
        url: '',
        fullscreenOnly: false, 
        displayTime: 0 
    },
    clip: {
        url: '...',
        autoPlay: false,
        scaling: 'orig'
    },
    canvas:{
        background: 'url(...) center center no-repeat',
        backgroundGradient: 'none'
    }
};
```

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPlugin('canvas')` is definitely a right way to get the canvas handler, and you can manipulate its appearance via call like:

```
getPlugin('canvas').css('', '');
```

In your case to hide the canvas, may be you can try `getPlugin("canvas").css({backgroundImage: ""});`.

See more ref in this [post](http://code.google.com/p/flowplayer-core/issues/detail?id=277)

Comment: But when I try this... I got the message "There is no plugin called 'canvas'."

Comment: Ok... sorry... using css on the canvas actually worked! But the default plugin methods won't work, because it says "There is no plugin called 'canvas'."

Comment: Hi Christian, may I ask you what's your way to get the plugin handler?

Comment: I tried "this" in the clip event onStart and $f('playerid') from outside the player context.